# AdapterContextMenuInfo.id

Tags: android

I have looked online about this. So my understanding is that AdapterContextMenuInfo.position is the index of the item in the listview.

Is AdapterContextMenuInfo.id the index of the item in the Cursor or the primary key id of the item in the database? I have used it as the primary key id of the item in the database. Are cursors indexed by primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is AdapterContextMenuInfo.id the index of the item in the Cursor or the primary key id of the item in the database?

It is the value of the `_id` column that is inside your `Cursor`, when you are using a `CursorAdapter`.

> Are cursors indexed by primary key?

`Cursors` are not indexed, period. However, to use `CursorAdapter`, you must have a column in the `Cursor`'s result set that has the name `_id`.

Comment: They are indexed in a way, because you can do cursor.moveToPosition(int) right?

Comment: @almostrufio: Well, insofar as an array is "indexed". I suppose it depends on your use of the term.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. If we think of the adapter as an array of the values and the cursor pointing to one row of the adapter, the row number (zero-based) of the adapter row is position.